# SIR model (gray) suceptible and (red) infected. keep getting Error in infected & close_contact : non-conformable arrays

Tags: r

*It wont print out the gray squares that are meant to represent the people susceptible and red squares that are meant to represent those infected*

```
initial1=function(m,l){
  x = matrix(0, nrow = m, ncol = l)
  new_infections=x
  close_contact=sample(c("S","I"), size=m*l, prob=c(0.9,0.1), replace=TRUE)
  close_contact[TRUE] = 1
  set.seed(12)
  close_contact = sample(c(T, F), size = m*l, replace = TRUE)
  close_contact = matrix(close_contact, nrow = m, ncol = l)
  infected = x[-50, ] == 1
  new_infections[-1, ][infected & close_contact] = 1
}

plot_infection= function(initial1){
  sir_colors=c("White", "Grey", "Red")
  x1=matrix(initial1, nrow = m)
  x1
  z=matrix(0, nrow=m, ncol=l)
  z[x1=="I"]=1
  par(mfrow = c(1,2))
  image(z, col = sir_colors)
  
  x2=matrix(initial2, nrow=m)
  z1=matrix(0, nrow=m, ncol=l)
  z1[x2=="S"]=1
  image(z1, col=sir_colors)
}

plot_infection(initial1(m,l))
```

Comment: I haven't read through the code yet but 1) this is wrong: `close_contact[TRUE] = 1`; 2) don't `set.seed(12)` inside a function; 3) in a function, `x1` alone does nothing; 4) `initial2` is not defined anywhere in the code.

Comment: Sorry i meant to change initial2 to initial1, and okay let me try to fix those!

Comment: Also, 5) you define `close_contact` as a sample of `c("S", "I")` and of `c(T, F)`. Which is it? 6) When you assign `infected = x[-50, ] == 1`, the matrix `x` is still zeros only, it never changed.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The following functions are much simpler and plot a graph according to the problem description.

```
initial1 <- function(m, l){
  new_infections <- sample(c(S = 2L, I = 3L), size = m*l, prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = TRUE)
  new_infections <- matrix(new_infections, nrow = m, ncol = l)
  close_contact <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = m*l, replace = TRUE)
  close_contact <- matrix(close_contact, nrow = m, ncol = l)
  new_infections[close_contact] <- 1L
  new_infections
}

plot_infection <- function(x){
  sir_colors <- c("white", "grey", "red")
  image(x, col = sir_colors)
}

m <- 50
l <- 50
set.seed(12)
init <- initial1(m, l)
plot_infection(init)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough information, my task is to use vectorized code (not a for loop) to randomly infect approximately 50% of the cells either above or below the infected cells

Comment: i have to create a side by side graph using par(mfrow=c(1,2) to show the initial amount infected then the next 50% either above or below the inital infected cells